# How to play song which is fetched from internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have fetched music from phone's internal storage and it is displaying perfectly but i don't know how to play these songs. Here is my code, please tell me how can i play it. I am not getting which URI i have to pass to play the song.

Help me to resolve this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music, container, false);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSTION_REQUEST);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSTION_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        doStuff();
    }

    return view;
}
public void doStuff(){
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.musicrecyclerview);
    musicModes = new ArrayList<>();
    getMusic();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, musicModes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent =new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        }
    });
}
public void getMusic(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor mycursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if(mycursor != null && mycursor.moveToFirst()){
        songtitle = mycursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        songsize = mycursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        column_index = mycursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        do{
            currenttitle = mycursor.getString(songtitle);
            currentsize = mycursor.getString(songsize);
            musicModes.add(currenttitle+ "\n"+ currentsize);
        } while(mycursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read about MediaPlayer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer

Comment: Yeah i have read it. But i am not getting in the place of URI what should i pass ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
int dataIndex= mycursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
String data =  mycursor.getString(dataIndex)
Uri uri= Uri.parse("file:///" + data);

MediaPlayer player= new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Comment: Tried this, but while parsing it is giving error:  parse(String) in Uri cannot be applied to (String, int)

Comment: I update the code. I forgot to extract actual data from cursor.

Comment: okay but still it is giving error, it is not accepting two arguments.

Comment: In my code I'm passing only one argument to Uri.parse() which is String created by concatenation of "file:///" and data

Comment: but still my problem is not solved, how to play this music?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you have problem only with getting URI.